# Changing the order of the stacked columns in vba

Tags: excel, vba, charts

community,

In VBA/Excel, how is the order of the stacked columns sorted? 
For instance, in the below chart, horse riding columns appear below the trekking columns. How does one put the horse riding columns above the others, in terms of VBA? Is it possible to decide the order of the stacked columns and fix it?

[image]

Comment: Change the `Series.PlotOrder` property.

Comment: Thanks, @Rory! I didn't know this property, it worked perfectly!
Where can I check all the available Series properties, do you know?

Comment: In the Object Browser (f2) in the VB Editor.